# Write a function to get a slice of string keys from a map no matter what value type the map is

Tags: go

I want to write a function to get all keys from a map as a slice of string which key type is string and the value could be any other type.

Like this but can have any kind of map[string]... as input.

```
func mapLowCaseKeys(v map[string]string) []string {
    keys := make([]string, len(v))
    i := 0
    for key := range v {
        keys[i] = strings.ToLower(key)
        i++
    }
    return keys
}
```

Actually I want achive `Object.keys()` in Javascript.

I've tried use `map[string]interface{}` as the function's paramter type but it can't just pass any specific map to that function, is this possible in golang?

Comment: No, this is not normally possible in Go. Technically, you could do something similar using reflection, but that will make your code slow and hard to read. Please avoid reflection at all costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use `MapKeys` in `reflect` package to do that(ref: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MapKeys).

> MapKeys returns a slice containing all the keys present in the map, in unspecified order. It panics if v's Kind is not Map. It returns an empty slice if v represents a nil map.

An example is given below (playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/xhDtmbGUyz0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(mapLowCaseKeys(map[string]float64{
        "key1" : 1.2,
    }))

    fmt.Println(mapLowCaseKeys(map[string]interface{} {
        "key1" : 1.2,
        "key2" : map[string]string{"kk": "3"},
    }))

    fmt.Println(mapLowCaseKeys(map[int]float64{
         11 : 1.2,
    }))

    fmt.Println(mapLowCaseKeys(nil))
}

func mapLowCaseKeys(v interface{}) []string {
    keys := []string{}
    value := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if value.Kind() == reflect.Map {
        for _, v := range value.MapKeys() {
            if v.Kind() == reflect.String {
                keys = append(keys, v.String())
            }
        }
        return keys
    } else {
        fmt.Println("it is not a map!!")
        return keys
    }
}
```